# Firebase with SAML authorization callback URL

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, saml, google-cloud-identity

Trying to get dot some Is and cross some Ts on getting SAML to function correctly with Firebase. I've followed Google's workflow on how to add SAML to a project (https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/how-to-enable-application-for-saml) but am hitting a wall with the authorization callback URL. When clicking the login to go to the SAML, it takes you to the provider's URL to sign in. But after logging in, you just get redirected back to the firebase site (*.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler), not the actual site. I've got the site URL set up as an authorized Domain in Firebase/Cloud Identity Platform. I'm not using Firebase hosting for the project, but I thought that as long as the URL is in the Authorized Domain, I didn't need to set up a redirect.

*3:26pm 2/26 - I think part of it might also be how I entered the SP Entity ID. I had used the same as the Entity ID that was with the SSO URL